# How to calculate the spin correlations in XXZ model under the longitudinal field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, correlation-functions

The Hamiltonian reads
$$H=\sum_i(S_i^xS_{i+1}^x+S_i^yS_{i+1}^y+\Delta S_i^zS_{i+1}^z)-h_z\sum_iS_i^z$$

How to calculate the $\langle S_i^xS_{i+1}^x\rangle$,  $\langle S_i^yS_{i+1}^y\rangle$, $\langle S_i^zS_{i+1}^z\rangle$ and  $\langle S_i^z\rangle$?